# Newb help in designing query to subtract results of two queries in same table

Tags: sql

I have seen other questions like this one but feel mine is a bit different, or didn't quite understand the SQL in the other questions...so my apologies if this one is redundant or very easy..

Anyway, I have an accounting transaction DB that stores every transaction posting within our financial system on one line. What I am trying to do is net the sum of the debits and the credits for each GL account.

Here are the two basic queries I am executing to get the results that I would like to net.

**Query 1** gives me the sum of all debit transactions posting to each gl account:

```
Select gl_debit, sum (amt) from FISC_YEAR2014 where fund = 'XXX'
group by gl_debit
```

**Query 2** gives me the sum of all credit transactions posting to each gl account:

```
select gl_credit, sum (amt) from FISC_YEAR2014 where fund = 'XXX'
group by gl_credt
```

Now I would to subtract the credit amounts from the debit amounts to get net totals for each gl account. Make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: What do `gl_credit` and `gl_debit` represent?  I assume they are not the debit/credit amounts, since you are summing the `amt` field.

Comment: The gl_credit and gl_debit columns represent the various GL account codes. The values within these columns are 101, 201, 301 etc.

Comment: Show us some example data, a few rows that would end up being a single row in the result. The main thing I need to know is if `gl_credit = gl_debit` for the amounts you need to subtract? Also what database engine are you using? MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle?

Comment: Using Oracle SQL developer to log in to the DB. Data in the table looks similar to:                                                        ***trans_date gl_debit gl_credt amt
3/1/2014 101 501  100.00 
3/2/2014 101 501  150.00 
3/3/2014 201 101  75.00 
3/4/2014 201 101  150.00 
3/5/2014 301 101  500.00***

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer. Yes, I believe the gl_credit = gl_debit. For example, there are ten rows of transactions with gl_debit = 101 with varying values in the amt column. There are also ten additional rows where gl_credit = 101 with varying values in the amt column. I am trying to net the values in the amt columns for all of the transactions where the transactions, where GL account code is  101, so I would take the credit lines minus the debit lines.

Comment: riiiiight, sorry I misunderstood the problem! So assuming those were the only rows, the result would be 101:-475, 201:225, 301:500, 501:-250, correct?

Comment: Hi @JRyan just wanted to know if you had looked at the answers

Comment: Yep, Joe put in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this depending our your table definition. I think your situation is the first.

This is the normal way assuming credits and debits are in separate columns:

```
SELECT sum(gl_debit)-sum(gl_credit) as net_debit 
FROM FISC_YEAR2014
WHERE fund = 'XXX'
```

This is the other way assuming direction is indicated by a separate column:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(is_debit=1,amount,-1*amount)) as net_debit 
FROM FISC_YEAR2014
WHERE fund = 'XXX'
```

See also:

- [MySQL 'IF' in 'SELECT' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/mysql-if-in-select-statement)
- [Can't calculate totals in general ledger report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297827/cant-calculate-totals-in-general-ledger-report)
- [What's a good way to store a financial ledger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001484/whats-a-good-way-to-store-a-financial-ledger)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
select
    gl_account,
    sum(amt)
from
(   
    select gl_debit gl_account,
           sum(-amt) amt 
      from fisc_year2014
     where fund = 'XXX'
     group by gl_debit
  union all
    select gl_credit,
           sum(amt)
      from fisc_year2014
     where fund = 'XXX'
     group by gl_credit
)
group by
    gl_account
```

There are two SELECTs: one to get the (negative) debits and another to get the credits.  They are UNIONed to create a two-column result.  The outer SELECT then aggregates the total sum by the `gl_account` code.  If there is a mismatch (a gl_debit without a gl_credit, or vice-versa), then its amount would still be displayed.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e062) (I added another row to show the effect of mismatched IDs)

Comment: Thanks Joe this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should `SUM` the debits and credits separately in subqueries, then join those subqueries on `gl_credit = gl_debit`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(gl_credit, gl_debit) AS Id
      ,COALESCE(d.amt,0)-COALESCE(c.amt,0) AS Net
FROM (
    SELECT gl_debit, SUM(amt) AS amt
    FROM FISC_YEAR2014
    GROUP BY gl_debit  
) d 
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT gl_credit, SUM(amt) AS amt
    FROM FISC_YEAR2014
    GROUP BY gl_credit  
) c ON d.gl_debit = c.gl_credit
ORDER BY COALESCE(gl_credit, gl_debit)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5aa9/11)

Outputs:

```
ID      Net
-----------
101    -475
201     225
301     500
501    -250
```

If I were you rather than using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, I'd select the `id`s from the accounts table or wherever you store them, then `LEFT JOIN` both of the subqueries to it, you haven't shown any other tables though so I can only speculate.